# Get Specific Value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a url:

> sys.php?x=23&y=20&z=9d939b

And I don't really know how to parse the 'z' value from it.

Comment: Also, that's not C# code, that's javascript

Comment: What i tried is only .Replace but the x and y values is change able so i don't know how could i get the value then

Comment: you are so smart Servy i want to get the value in a C# code and i never said this is a C# code. does it seems that for you ?

Comment: @RuneS Do you want to access the value from an ASP page responding to that request?  Do you have a string in a C# app that you need to parse, is this a console/asp/mvc/silverlight/winphone/other application?  You need to supply context.  For all I know you need to do the parsing from within the javascript code; if not, why would you post this javascript code?  If you really are parsing it outside of javascript then the posted code is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: it is not java script that i want to parse see bud this is just a part of a html page that i want to get the value of it

Comment: My answer below is in C#

Comment: @RuneS I'm simply explaining how you have not sufficiently described your problem.  There are all sorts of ways of interpreting what you have said.  Until you are clear about what you want it's not possible to answer the question, and until you can demonstrate what you've done and what specific problems you're having with this task of yours it won't be a *good* question.

Comment: @RuneS I don't mean to be a jerk, but I want to flag this question since it doesn't seem like it is possible to answer. Where is the URL coming from and what are you doing with in WinForm that you need to parse javascript.

Comment: Do you see the answer below ? how could YYY answered it although being un answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` method, detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx).  It'll return a collection that gives you all the names (x,y,z), and the values (23, 20, 3d939b).

Comment: but how could this function query the string [on which bases it work]

Comment: @RuneS You just feed it the string, and it returns a collection that allows you to access the keys and the values in the query part of the string.  You would move through it using a `foreach` or a LINQ `.Select()` or really any other way you wanted to process it.  C# is pretty generous with manipulating collections.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var zValue = Request.QueryString["z"];
```

Comment: what is Request i never heard about that

Comment: @RuneS It's a property that's made available in ASP contexts when you inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page`.

Comment: The syntax written in the answer.  That is a C# code example.

Comment: i am working in Windows Forms

Comment: @RuneS That's the kind of thing that's worth mentioning in your question, and tagging to it as well.